# Just trying to setup Rails and I have a few concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install Rails (On Mac OSX) and I basically have it all done now, but I'm currently learning from a book that uses SQLite 3, I just want to use MySQL, will the statements for talking to the Database be the same throughout the book? Also, when you set your Mysql password/username you do so in `/config/database.yml` but that's visible from the web, and anybody can navigate there and see my password and what not, is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ActiveRecord will abstract any interaction with your database. As long as you use it you don't have to worry if you are on SQLite or MySQL.
- The only public facing folder is the `public` folder. This contrasts with PHP applications where everything is exposed (and must be exposed in order for the web server to interact with it).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if I use SQLite3, is there a file I can move into my webserver and just use it like that? Or do I need to use MySQL for my webhosts, if I can get away with SQLite3 then that is fine. Also the /config/database.yml isn't in my public/ folder, yet I can see it just fine, are you saying on my webserver I need to move it outside the /www folder?

Comment: How are you running your Rails app? `rails s`?

Comment: If I understand what you mean, I generated the code, rails new blah -d mysql, and drag-dropped it into my /www on my webhost @istvanp

Comment: Ah. I think you skipped a part of the book :P Rails cannot be run directly from a web server like Apache or nginx. You must use a web server (or module) made to run a Ruby application like Passenger, mongrel, unicorn and so on. The easiest is to run WEBrick which comes with Rails. Just run `rails s` at the command line like when you did `rails new`. Suffice to say, move out your whole application from `www`.

Comment: alright I'm officially lost and I am on page 35, so how do I put my rails on the web then, I'm using hosting24.com which says it has Ruby On Rails support, care to explain? I'm a die hard PHP developer and I'm so used to just drag and dropping everything :P

Comment: I am not familiar with hosting24 but they must have documentation on how to properly setup a RoR application on their platform. Unfortunately I can't point you to the pertinent doc as I can't find it on their website. They must have it behind their customer login. I suggest you first get familiar with RoR by running your server locally (that is, just run `rails s` on your machine).

Comment: so I am free to use SQLite 3 then?

Comment: Yes, and try making your app work on your own machine (`rails s`!) before trying to put it up on the web.

Comment: Thanks for the help, cleared up actually quite a bit, one last question, how hard of a learning curve is Rails, and if I learn Rails can I write in Ruby just fine? And will it make me happier than PHP :D?

Comment: After you learn Rails, and by extension, Ruby, you will wonder why you put up with PHP in the first place :) The learning curve isn't steep if you come from a programming background and you don't do anything fancy besides what Rails gives you (Ruby has some complexity that you will only discover over time). You should probably also look into CoffeeScript, which is a very Ruby flavoured version of JavaScript and now default in Rails for writing JS. You won't be disappointed learning these, that I assure you :)

Comment: Thanks for the help man, I'll continue reading my book, I got PHP down to a science, but I hate how much I have to repeat myself with it, and I read RoR is all about not repeating so, here I go! Thanks again!